# accessing and updating different objects of an array in d3

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, d3.js

I did:

```
var dummy_array=[];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    dummy_array.push(0);
};

var data=[],dataCheck = [];

    data['data0']=dummy_array;
    data['data1']=dummy_array;
    data['data0'].shift();
    data['data0'].push(5);
    console.log(data['data0']);
    console.log(data['data1']);
}
```

Instead of `data['data0']` getting updated, `data['data1']` also gets updated.

I want only `data['data0']` to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data['data0']=dummy_array.sclice(0);
data['data1']=dummy_array.sclice(0);
```